# Почему последний элемент в новом массиве undefined

Tags: javascript

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const b = ['d', 'e']

const c = []

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
  if (a[i] != null) {
    c.push(a[i])
  }

  if (b[i] != null) {
    c.push(b[i])
  }
}

console.log(c) //[ 'a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', undefined ]
```

Данный код последним элементом в массив добавляет undefined. Из-за чего это происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что длина массивов не совпадает. А проверку следует делать не на null, а на отсутствие элемента.

Comment: @Visman Как это можно исправить?

Comment: В приведенном вами примере в *chrome v60* `undefined` в конце нету.

Comment: В результате выполнения сниппета - никакого undefined нет

Comment: @Visman, в данном случае - это одно и то же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
var b = ['d', 'e']

var c = []

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
  if (a[i] != undefined) {
    c.push(a[i])
  }

  if (b[i] != undefined) {
    c.push(b[i])
  }
}

console.log(c)
```

Answer (score -1):

Выход за размерность массива.

Исправляется так:

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const b = ['d', 'e']

const c = []

for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, b.length); i++) {
  if (a.length > i && a[i] != null) {
    c.push(a[i])
  }

  if (b.length > i && b[i] != null) {
    c.push(b[i])
  }
}

console.log(c) //[ 'a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', undefined ]
```